# Calculated Value Changing when issue tracking list has been resolved

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

*Hope someone can help me with this issue.  I am currently using the following formula to calculate a number of hours a ticket has taken to complete.
    =IF(Completed="","",INT(((Completed-Created)*24)))
when I go into complete a ticket the number changes.

```
                     Created           completed              duration (hrs)
First Example (OK)      26/07/2016 12:23   26/07/2016 19:00              6.00 

Second Example (Not OK) 26/07/2016 13:46   26/07/2016 13:00       1,021,861.00
```

the workaround at the moment is I go into the list settings and then click on the edit column and just hit OK without making any changes.  this refreshes the date.  I am not sure how to set this up so it refreshes automatically. 
thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

Have thought of making a workflow that loops every 24 hours while it is not completed that updates the duration. It would look like(sudo workflow)

1. Loop until status = completed
2. Wait until time add 24 hours(or whatever interval) to time
3. do calculation between today and created
4. set field duration to = calculation

Comment: Not sure that was corrupting this.  I had to create a new list and since then it has worked absolutely fine without any issues.  thanks for your help